# How to initialize a char array from a char pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to initialize a local `char array` with a `string`, which is generated to a static const pointer. Basically it looks like this:

```
static const char * const FOO = "foo"; /* generated */
char bar[12] = FOO;                    /* my code */
```

The compiler does not accept it:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

What construct can I use to initialize the `char array` bar with the `string` pointed to by `FOO`?

> **Context**: in my company, we write unit testers for C code using a C++
>   framework. Therefore the bar parameter must be an array and cannot be
>   a C++ string type. The FOO constant is generated from a proprietary
>   IDL. The code generator generates a #define for C code, but a static
>   const char * const for C++.

Comment: `char bar[12]; strcpy(bar, FOO);`?

Comment: Do you need to modify the string at all? If not, why not just stay with the pointer?

Comment: @Aconcagua: yes the string must be modified later.

Comment: @mch and Thomas Sablik: your solutions would work, but if possible I'd like a one-line solution.

Comment: I would add `Assert(sizeof bar > strlen(FOO));` to the test code. And thereafter `strcpy(bar, FOO);`. This makes your tester more robust agains changes in the generated code.

Comment: *'Therefore the bar parameter must be an array and cannot be a C++ string type'* – well, only if the C-Code needs to access *and* modify that string as well. Would it do so?

Comment: @Aconcagua: yes, it does exactly that.

Comment: Can you post an example test case and why do you double initialize the const char*? Just call it  >>>> const char* foo = "foo"; <<<<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialise the array with the pointer. But you can copy the string after default-initialising the array.

> in my company, we write unit testers for C code using a C++ framework. Therefore the bar parameter must be an array and cannot be a C++ string type.

I don't follow your reasoning. This seems like a mistaken assumption.

Comment: The bar variable is used as input for a C function under test that takes a char array as parameter.

Comment: @slingeraap That's what the `c_str` member function is for.

Comment: The parameter is changed by the function and `c_str` returns a const type.

Comment: @slingeraap In that case you can use `data` member function (since C++17; In older standards you can use `&bar[0]`).

Comment: But we still need C++11, before, `std::string` should be out...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah, pre-C++11 lacks some guarantees so modifying `std::string` through a char pointer should be avoided prior to C++11.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that the following would work:

```
static const char * const FOO = "foo"; /* generated */
char bar[12], *pBar = strcpy(bar, FOO);                    /* my code */
```

and then you could either access it via `bar[]` or through `pBar`.

There is a redundancy of the extra `char *` but it may be that it doesn't really matter.

You might even consider something like the following to guard against buffer overflow:

```
static const char * const FOO = "foo"; /* generated */
char bar[12] = {0}, *pBar = strncpy(bar, FOO, sizeof(bar)/sizeof(bar[0]) - 1);                    /* my code */
```

You may also consider wrapping this in a `#define` as in:

```
#define MAKEARRAY(name, size, thing) char name[size] = {0}, *p##name = strncpy(name, (thing), (size) - 1)
```

and then using it like:

```
MAKEARRAY(bar2, 14, FOO);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but IMHO looks ugly:

```
static const char *const X = "abc";
char x[12] = { X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3] };
```

Defines would work:

```
#define X "abc"
char x[12] = X;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal but should give you an idea. It uses local variables so they won't persist beyond these functions. I'm not sure you were using Static how you thought it should be used. I'd recommend NOT putting it in the function since you can't really access it outside of the function, but it will remain in memory.

```
void ModifyString(char* data, int length)
{
    std::cout << "Data: " << data << ", Length: " << length;
}

void ModifyString(const char* data)
{
    char buffer[256];
    int length = -1;
    while (data[++length])
        buffer[length] = data[length];
    buffer[length] = 0;
    ModifyString(buffer, length);
}

int main() 
{
    ModifyString("Hello Test");
    return 0;
}
```